# Meteor: Publish/Subscribe Without Removing Auto-publish?

Tags: meteor

Hi I just get in touch with Meteor. First impression, cool...

I have question, is it possible to use publish/subscribe without removing autopublish?

I mean use both autopublish and publish/subscribe together. In certain part of app will be best using autopublish. In other part of app will be best using publish/subscribe

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using autopublish, it becomes a global service of your app so using manual publish/subscribe would be redundant.

However, there is a subtle feature of a publication, its name.

If you don't give a name to a publication, the contents of the publication is delivered to *all connected clients*. For example:

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
  return Posts.find();
})
```

Now in order to get your `Posts` from the client, you don't have to subscribe. It will already be there.

Answer (score 1):

No. Autopublish puts *all* the data from the server onto the client. Any publish/subscribe used in addition to autopublish will be redundant.